# How to justify text in drawtext in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am adding text watermarks to the video using ffmpeg command and I've added three lines already using `drawtext` in ffmpeg command. So, it works perfectly and adds three lines at the bottom left corner of the video.

In the first line there are 25 characters, the second line contains 7 characters, and the third line contains 3 characters. These three lines are located from the left to right.

So, I want to justify 2nd and 3rd line's texts to the center as per the first line width.

What I get:

```
Hello World Ffmpeg

hello

hel
```

what I want:

```
Hello World Ffmpeg

      hello

       hel
```

here command i used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "[in]drawtext=fontsize=20:fontcolor=White:fontfile='roboto.ttf':text='Hello World Ffmpeg':x=(w)/2:y=(h)/2, drawtext=fontsize=20:fontcolor=White:fontfile='roboto.ttf':text='hello':x=(w)/2:y=((h)/2)+25, drawtext=fontsize=20:fontcolor=White:fontfile='roboto.ttf':text='hel':x=(w)/2:y=((h)/2)+50[out]" -y test_out.mp4
```

Comment: Can you please also share the command which you've used?

Comment: ok wait i am adding.

Comment: i updated my post see the command.

Comment: Actually, there is a `tw` ( text width ) which you can use for this. So, for the second text `x` value you need to have something like `(tw1 - tw2)/2` and for the third text: `(tw1-tw3)/2`. But actually, I'm not sure how you can use `tw1`, `tw2` or `tw3` in different `drawtext` as for each one the `tw` gives you the corresponding text width.

Comment: can you give me any example to understand it?

Comment: In your command, you've used `x=(w)/2`. The `w` here is the width of the video. So, please change it to `x=(w-tw)/2` for each `drawtext` and you should have all the texts at the center of the video

Comment: Is `Hello World Ffmpeg` supposed to be centered on the x axis in relation to the video? Or is the placement of x arbitrary?